# Como ter um boa identação de .blade no VSCode?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, visual-studio-code

Exemplo de resultado esperado:

```
<body>
    @extends('t')
    @include('as')
</body>
```

Exemplo de Realidade com [extensão PHP](https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt)

```
<body>
    @extends('t') @include('as')
</body>
```

Comment: Cara pq vc não usa algo tipo isso! https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade Acho que o VS Code não entende que ele tem que quebrar a linha sempre antes de um @

Comment: @hugocsl eu uso este, ajuda bastante mesmo. Quero ver se alguém conseguiu resolver isso além das extensões

Comment: Está a usar alguma extensão para blade ?

Comment: Estou apenas para snippets https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade

Comment: @DavidDias pensa comigo, porque tem que dar um pulo de linha se você tem que escrever o paramento dentro do parenteses ? e outra para digitar outro comando de um enter, não é isso!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado pela resposta. Na verdade o problema não é exatamente na escrita, o problema é quando você executa o identador automático para alinhar tudo, assim como faço com o PHP, entendeu? No caso do PHP, ele já enquadra tudo para PSR-2 e fica lindo

Comment: Quais são os comandos para fazer isso?

Comment: Veja aqui: https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter

Comment: é muito prático, tudo fica padronizado e confortável de trabalhar

Comment: Mas isso para o PHP. Estou usando apenas de exemplo, o objetivo é resolver a pergunta para o blade

Comment: Eu até consegui fazer funcionar, mas, o que está na sua pergunta são extends e include, o extends por padrão cola na lateral do código. e na verdade ele não faz correto todas as tags o plugin não tem todas as caracteristicas, acredito que abrir um issue no seu pacote seja o ideal

Comment: Abra um issue aqui explicando problema: https://github.com/onecentlin/laravel-blade-snippets-vscode/issues !

Comment: @VirgilioNovic mas este pacote apenas faz os snippets pelo que vi, ele não atual quando fazemos a auto identaçaão

Comment: Ela tem no sua descrição formatação! eu li a documentação, mas, é a medida de associação de teclas, agora ele ainda não é o ideal, abra o issue que é melhor exponha seu problema no próprio desenvolvedor!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ótimo, mas a ideia dessa pergunta é ver se alguém já resolveu isso de alguma forma, não exatamente com esta extensão, foi apenas um exemplo. Obrigado de qualquer forma :)

Comment: Então se precisa entender o seguinte que pelo que pude pesquisar ainda não nenhum plugin, existe um que não faz a formatação do jeito que você deseja, então, aqui é um meio talvez de alguém saber, mas, eu sinceramente utilizo a formatação do próprio editor, para tal e me satisfaz, abrir um issue é de grande valia, para você e para os demais, depois você vem aqui e coloca como resposta, mas, `.blade`   para Laravel poucos mexem e a comunidade Laravel que eu participo também não sabe ... a idéia de pacotes é abrir correções vai lá e tente também por lá!

Comment: Excelente @VirgilioNovic, vou fazer isso